# Why my !ban command dosen't work (User not found) DISCORD.NET / C#

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I'm trying to make a bot using Discord.NET in C#. If I try to ban a user with my command, an error is returned on my console app : **User not found**

My other commands are working

My Task HandleCommandAsync :

```
    public async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage socketMessage)
    {
        var message = socketMessage as SocketUserMessage;
        var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message);

        if (message.Author.IsBot)
            return;

        int caracterPos = 0;
        if(message.HasStringPrefix("!", ref caracterPos))
        {
            var result = await _commands.ExecuteAsync(context, caracterPos, _services);
            if (!result.IsSuccess)
                Console.WriteLine(result.ErrorReason);
            if (result.Error.Equals(CommandError.UnmetPrecondition))
                await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync(result.ErrorReason);
        }
    }
```

*result.ErrorReason* => "User not found"

*await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync(result.ErrorReason);* => don't send a message

My command in my commands.cs class :

```
    [Command("ban")]
    [RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.BanMembers, ErrorMessage = "Tu n'as pas la permission de bannir des membres !")]
    public async Task BanMember(SocketGuildUser user = null, [Remainder] string reason = null)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            await ReplyAsync("Aucun Utilisateur spécifié");
            return;
        }
        if (reason == null)
            reason = "Raison non-spécifiée";

        var embedBuilder = new EmbedBuilder()
            .WithDescription($":white_check_mark: {user.Mention} a été banni\n**Raison :** {reason}")
            .WithColor(new Color(255,0,0));
        Embed embed = embedBuilder.Build();
        await ReplyAsync(embed: embed);
        await Context.Guild.AddBanAsync(user, 0, reason);
    }
```

My command in Discord : !ban @user reason

Thanks for your help !

LPR

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64571478/11159372

Comment: It was that ! Thanks @Anu6is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must activate that in your discord application -> Bot :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
        config = new DiscordSocketConfig
        {
            AlwaysDownloadUsers = true,
            MessageCacheSize = 100,
            GatewayIntents =
            GatewayIntents.Guilds |
            GatewayIntents.GuildMembers |
            GatewayIntents.GuildMessageReactions |
            GatewayIntents.GuildMessages |
            GatewayIntents.GuildVoiceStates
        };
        DiscordSocketClient client = new DiscordSocketClient(config);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31311920)