# Discord.Net Roles don´t Update in the Bot

Tags: c#, discord.net

I´m writing a DiscordBot for rainbow6 tournaments, users can create teams with the bot, add Players to it and only the team Captain can edit the Team. In case the Teams need to change the Captain i wrote a command -givecaptian to change the team captain and some depending data in the Database.

```
[Command("givecaptain")]
        public async Task givecaptain(string UplayName, [Remainder] string mention = null)
        {
            if (Context.Channel.Id == TextChannels.TurnierCommands)
            {
                var guildUser = Context.Guild.GetUser(Context.Message.Author.Id);
                if (guildUser.Roles.Contains(Context.Guild.GetRole(Roles.TeamCaptain)))
                {
                    var helper = new SpaceCupDataSetHelper();
                    var dataSet = helper.GetSpaceCupDataSet();
                    helper.FillDataSet(dataSet);

                    SpaceCupDataSet.TeamCaptainRow captain = null;
                    try
                    {
                        captain = dataSet.TeamCaptain.Single(x => x.DCUserID == (long)guildUser.Id);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        await Context.Message.DeleteAsync();
                        var m = await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Du konntest in der Datenbank nicht gefunden werden. Kontaktiere bitte den Support. (-support Grund)");
                        await Task.Delay(5000);
                        await m.DeleteAsync();
                        return;
                    }

                    var team = dataSet.Team.Single(x => x.TeamCaptain == captain.CaptainID);
                    var spieler = dataSet.Spieler.Where(x => x.TeamID == team.TeamID);

                    SpaceCupDataSet.SpielerRow newCaptainSpieler = null;

                    SpaceCupDataSet.TeamCaptainRow newCaptain = null;
                    try
                    {
                        if (mention != null)
                        {
                            var mentionedID = Convert.ToInt64(mention.Split('!')[1].TrimEnd('>'));
                            newCaptainSpieler = spieler.Single(x => x.DCUserId == mentionedID);

                            captain.CaptainName = newCaptainSpieler.UplayName;
                            captain.DCUserID = mentionedID;

                            newCaptain = captain;
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }

                    try
                    {
                        if (newCaptain == null)
                        {
                            newCaptainSpieler = spieler.Single(x => x.UplayName.TrimEnd(' ') == UplayName);

                            if (newCaptainSpieler.DCUserId != 0)
                            {
                                captain.CaptainName = newCaptainSpieler.UplayName;
                                captain.DCUserID = newCaptainSpieler.DCUserId;

                                newCaptain = captain;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }

                    if (newCaptain != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var newUser = Context.Guild.GetUser((ulong)newCaptain.DCUserID);
                            await newUser.AddRoleAsync(Context.Guild.GetRole(Roles.TeamCaptain));
                            await guildUser.RemoveRoleAsync(Context.Guild.GetRole(Roles.TeamCaptain));

                            helper.saveChanges(dataSet);

                            await Context.Message.DeleteAsync();
                            var m = await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Die Rolle wurde erfolgreich übergeben.");
                            await Task.Delay(3000);
                            await m.DeleteAsync();
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            await Context.Message.DeleteAsync();
                            var m = await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Du musst mit dem Spieler in einem Voicechannel auf diesem Discord sein, um die Rolle zu übergeben.");
                            await Task.Delay(5000);
                            await m.DeleteAsync();
                        }
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await Context.Message.DeleteAsync();
                        var m = await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Es konnte kein Spieler gefunden werden. Der Spieler muss bereits in deinem Team sein, damit du die TeamCaptain Rolle übergeben kannst.");
                        await Task.Delay(5000);
                        await m.DeleteAsync();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    await Context.Message.DeleteAsync();
                    var m = await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Du musst der Captain deines Teams sein um die Captainrolle zu übergeben.");
                    await Task.Delay(5000);
                    await m.DeleteAsync();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await Context.Message.DeleteAsync();
                var m = await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Bitte nutze den turnier-commands Channel um mit mir zu schreiben.");
                await Task.Delay(5000);
                await m.DeleteAsync();
            }
        }
```

The command does what it´s supposed to, it takes away the role and reassigns it to the new Discord User if he is on the Discord.

But if I try to use any other command afterwards it cant find the role on the SocketGuildUser (the new Teamcaptain). If i Debug it SocketGuildUser.roles shows a Count of 3, but if i open the list it only displays 2 Roles, but not the one im looking for. It can only find the role if i restart the bot after using this command.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try enabling the server member intents - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64571478/11159372

Comment: Thank that worked out perfectly ^^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling the server member intents - stackoverflow.com/a/64571478/11159372 – Anu6is

Thank that worked out perfectly ^^.

Thanks to Anu6is ^^