# Get all users from text channel in dsharp c#

Tags: c#, .net, discord, bots, dsharp+

I wanna get list of all users in text channel by channel id.
I tried this with that code:

```
var channel = ctx.Guild.GetChannel(id);

var users = channel.Users;

foreach (var item in users)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

*(id = channel-id)*

but instead of list of all users, i got only two users: me and bot.

Comment: This could be helpful to look at [Guild members are not populated anymore, cannot GetUserAsync as it only returns the bot and no one else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64566016/guild-members-are-not-populated-anymore-cannot-getuserasync-as-it-only-returns)

Comment: @The2Step, this answer can't solve problem